# Access NSArray from multiple views

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsarray, nsobject

I have a data controller class used within my app that handles parsing xml and a few other operations vital to my app. What I want to be able to do is have the data that it parses store in an array that can be accessed in multiple views of my app. Right now, each view creates its own instance of the data controller class and so the array that the data is stored in is specific to that view controller. Is there a way to still create individual instances of the data controller class for each view controller, but the data is stored in the array where all views can access it? I have tried to store in NSUserDefaults but that doesn't seem the most effective way. Each view controller needs to have its own instance of the data controller class because I utilize delegate methods that are used in each of the view controllers. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to implement this (ok, maybe more than two but those are most common):

- Store array in application delegate and acces it as property.
- Create singleton object who gonna hold array (and other possible data/methods).

Comment: Which one would you prefer out of the two?

Comment: If you have small app, and only one array then application delegate is quite ok. But if you are planning to have more shared data then using app delegate for this purpose can become a real mess. Therefore i prefer using singleton object, because this is good programming practice, and more correct way to do the thing.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Can I still utilize delegate methods within a singleton? My thoughts would be no because you only have one instance so how would it know who initialized it?